# C# beginner question about using data from another method

Tags: c#

i am a beginner in C# (just started a course) and im running in a problem, i have to make a basic program that asks about a pet name, age and gender.At the end i need the program to remember the gender and print out good boy/girl based on readAndSavePetData and i have no idea how to, i also need to make it print out the name, age and gender on different lines instead of "name:name  Age:age name is a good boy/girl"

Program.cs

{

```
class MainProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Create object of the Pet class
        Pet petObj = new Pet();
        //Use object
        petObj.start();
        petObj.readAndSavePetData();
        petObj.displayPetInfo();


    }
}
```

}

Pet.cs

```
{
class Pet
{
    private string name; //name of pet
    private int age; //age as number
    private bool isFemale; //true if female, false if not female

    public void start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(); //empty line
        Console.WriteLine("Greetings from the Pet Owner app!");
        Console.WriteLine(); //empty line 2
    }
    public void readAndSavePetData()
    {
        //read text
        Console.WriteLine("What is the name of your pet?");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        //read number
        Console.WriteLine("what is " + name + "'s age?");
        string textValue = Console.ReadLine();
        //convert string to number
        age = int.Parse(textValue);
        //read value (y/n)
        Console.WriteLine("Is Your pet a female (y/n)?");
        string strGender = Console.ReadLine();
        strGender = strGender.Trim();
        char response = strGender[0];
        if ((response == 'y') || (response == 'Y'))
             isFemale = true;
        else
             isFemale = false;
    }
    public void displayPetInfo()
    {
        string textOut = "Name: " + name + " Age: " + age;
        Console.WriteLine(textOut);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You are calling `Console.WriteLine`. It writes a line of text to the console. If you want to write multiple lines of text to the console, what do you suppose you should do?

Comment: "What is Fluffy's name?" "I don't know" fatal kernel panic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> print out good boy/girl based on readAndSavePetData and i have no idea how to

Just check `isFemale` value and display message based on this value in your `displayPetInfo` method:

```cs
if (isFemale)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Good girl!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Good boy!");
}
```

At a later stage of learning, you can use [`?:` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) to make it as *one-liner*:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(isFemale ? "Good girl!" : "Good boy!");
```

> i also need to make it print out the name, age and gender on different lines instead of "name:name Age:age name is a good boy/girl"

To make new lines in command prompt, you should use `\n` (new line) escape character:

```cs
string textOut = "Name: " + name + "\nAge: " + age + "\n";

// Continued magic...
```

To make it easier, you should make [`string` interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) and [`Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline) call to support new line character as cross-platform application:

```cs
string textOut = $"Name: {name}{Environment.NewLine}Age: {age}";

// Continued magic...
```

Or just make it as multiline `string`:

```cs
string textOut = @$"Name: {name}
Age: {age}";

// Continued magic...
```

Comment: It's very important to understand that `isFemale` is a member of the `Pet` class and not a variable within the `readAndSavePetData` method, otherwise it would be in a different scope and not available in the `displayPetInfo` method. For that reason (among others) it's advisable to always use `this.` to identify that it's a class member and not a variable. e.g. `this.isFemail == true` and `if (this.isFemale)`